# Shebang expression

Tags: shebang

In one of my shell script(say abc.sh) I have below Sleeptime if condition, whenever sleeptime is passed as null in arguments, -1 is getting defaulted. this logic works fine in ksh but not in bash, reason being -eq relational operator does not work in bash while comparing null strings. to resolve this I have added shebang expression #!/bin/ksh at the beginning of my script.

```
if [ "$Sleeptime" -eq "" ]; then

            Sleeptime=-1
fi
```

After adding shebang expression to my script, comparison and defaulting are working fine, but when my abc.sh is executed from other customs sh file, comparison & defaulting is not working, I tried adding shebang expression in the custom sh file also but still facing the issue. Any pointers please to resolve an issue.

custom sh file content:

```
 #!/bin/ksh

cd /opt/common/config/

sh abc.sh $1 $2 $3

$3- is the sleeptime argument
```